# Access methods of js module with Jasmine so they can be individually tested

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, nativescript

I'm doing some unit testing with Jasmine. I have a module `getContacts` which is successfully injected to the spec using `module.exports` and `require`. Though I have access to the module itself, the modules methods are returning undefined so I am not able to test them as units. Below is the code for the module:

```
var getContacts = function() {

    var GetContacts = this;
    var contacts = require('nativescript-contacts');
    var model = require("../main-view-model");

    GetContacts.init = (function() {
        var self = this;
        contacts.getContact().then(function(args){
            self.makeName(args.data);
            self.getPhoneNumber(args.data);
        }).catch(function(e) {
            console.log("promise \"contacts.getContact()\" failed with" + e.stack + "\n" + "value of self:" + " " + self)
        });
    }());

    GetContacts.getPhoneNumber = function(data) {
        if(data.phoneNumbers.length > 0){
            model.phone = data.phoneNumbers[0];
        }
    };

    GetContacts.makeName = function(data) {
        if(data.name.displayname) {
            model.contactName = data.name.displayname;
        }
        else {

        }
        model.contactName = data.name.given + " " + data.name.family;
    };
};

module.exports = getContacts;
```

and the spec file:

```
describe("getContacts", function() {
    "use strict";

    var contacts, model, getContacts, data;

    beforeEach(function() {
        contacts = require('nativescript-contacts');
        model = require("../main-view-model");
        getContacts = require('../src/getContacts.js');

        data = {
            "data": {
                "name": {
                    "given": "John",
                    "middle": "Peter",
                    "family": "Smith",
                    "prefix": "Mr.",
                    "suffix": "Jr.",
                    "testEmptyObject": {},
                    "testEmptyString": "",
                    "testNumber": 0,
                    "testNull": null,
                    "testBool": true,
                    "displayname": "John Smith",
                    "phonetic": {
                        "given": null,
                        "middle": null,
                        "family": null
                    }
                }
            },
            "response": "selected"
        }
    });

    it("Gets the display name as contact name if display name is a string with length", function() {
        expect(getContacts.makeName(data)).toBe("John Smith");
    });

});
```

The test fails with the error:

> `getContacts.makeName` is not a function

and indeed logging it returns `undefined`. Logging `getContacts` however prints the entire `getContacts` function to the console. How to I access `makeName` and other methods so I can unit test them at an individual level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code needed to be restructured without the wrapping anonymous function. I suppose it isn't needed since the module itself creates separation. Here is the code that worked:

var contacts = require('nativescript-contacts');
var model = require("../main-view-model");

```
var GetContacts = {

    init: function() {
        var self = this;
        contacts.getContact().then(function(args){
            model.contactName = self.makeName(args.data);
            model.phone = self.getPhoneNumber(args.data);
        }).catch(function(e) {
            console.log("promise \"contacts.getContact()\" failed with" + e.stack + "\n" + "value of self:" + " " + self)
        });
    },

    getPhoneNumber: function(data) {
        if(data.phoneNumbers.length > 0){
            return data.phoneNumbers[0];
        }
    },

    makeName: function(data) {
        if(data.name.displayname) {
            return data.name.displayname;
        }
        else {
        }
    }

};
```

module.exports = GetContacts;

Answer (score 0):

function don't return anything so function will do something but won't know further reference to code inside of it, so try add return at end of function like below ;)

```
var getContacts = function() {

    var GetContacts = this;

    /*
    rest of code
    */

    GetContacts.makeName = function(data) {
        if(data.name.displayname) {
            model.contactName = data.name.displayname;
        }
        else {
        }
        model.contactName = data.name.given + " " + data.name.family;
    };

    //add return to export content of function
    return GetContacts;
};
```